# live chart for heartbeats

Tags: php, html, database, highcharts

guys i want to build a website that display heartbeats values 
and theses values taken from database so the values will insert automatically according to that i need live chart to achieve the goal so i search and found Highcharts website but i never deal with JavaScript also i use Notepad++ editor 
when i copied the source code all i get is plank space 
i don't know what to do and i really need live chart for my purpose 
and i want to tell you that i used this code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

that was for *HTML* 
and this for JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' 
+
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Heartbeats data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
    });
 });
```

my questions are that 
1- what i have to put in html src? 
2- why it show plank space when i tried to run it on localhost

Comment: Highcharts.chart is not inside of $(document).ready. Chart cannot be created before it's container loads

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out, and it is working for me try the snippet below.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    global: {
                        useUTC: false
                    }
                });

                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'spline',
                        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                        marginRight: 10,
                        events: {
                            load: function () {

                                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                                var series = this.series[0];
                                setInterval(function () {
                                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                            y = Math.random();
                                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Live random data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickPixelInterval: 150
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>'
                                    +
                                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                            name: 'Heartbeats data',
                            data: (function () {
                                // generate an array of random data
                                var data = [];
                                var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                                var i;

                                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                                    data.push({
                                        x: time + i * 1000,
                                        y: Math.random()
                                    });
                                }
                                return data;
                            }())
                        }]
                });
            });
```

```html
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        
        
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
        </div>
```

Comment: can i edit this code to take data from database automatically? also its not working on localhost :(